# Under which set of conditions a function could have just one local minimizer?

Tags: linear-algebra

Would be enough to demonstrate that:

$f$ is continuous (1)

$∇f = 0$ at that given point - $ x^* $ (2)

$H(f) = 0 $   at that given point - $ x^* $ (3)

in order to make the case that a particular function $ f $ has only one local minimizer $ x^* $

If yes, why is this the case?
What if we consider f a non-continous function then how this would change the situation?

Comment: No. These conditions aren't even sufficient to show that $x^*$ is a local minimizer. Showing a local min is a global min requires some global information about the function, such as  convexity.

Comment: What if we're considering just a specific neighborhood  - immediate vicinity of points - that encompasses all the subjected x amongst just one should be chosen. Then, would convexity still present a necessity to prove?

Comment: The function $f(x,y) = x^4$ is a counterexample to your statement. It contains infinitely many local minima along the line $x = 0$.

Comment: Could you check  Numerical Optimization by Nocedal & Wright, Solutions, Problem 2.1 just to see the motif upon which this case relies?